rewrite a working datastep to encode image to base64 in SAS into pure macro language (without datastep & proc´s)
I´ve found a program which encodes/decodes Image-data to base64 and vice versa:
https://support.selerity.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/223345708-Tip-SAS-and-Base64
For my purpose I need a solution, which does the encoding without using any datastep or proc´s
Sourcecode:
%macro base64(
         OPERATION=ENCODE,   /* ENCODE or DECODE */
         FILEMODE=,          /* Create a new file (BLANK) or add to existing file (MOD) */
         INPUT=,             /* Input FILEREF or FILENAME */
         OUTPUT=             /* Output FILEREF or FILENAME */
         );
  %* Parameter Checks;
  %let OPERATION=%upcase(&OPERATION);
  %let FILEMODE=%upcase(&FILEMODE);
  %if %str(&OPERATION) NE %str(ENCODE) and %str(&OPERATION) NE %str(DECODE) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: The only operations supported is ENCODE or DECODE.;
    %put ERROR: You specified %trim(&OPERATION).;
    %return;
  %end; 
  %if %str(&FILEMODE) NE %str(MOD) %then %do;
    %if %str(&FILEMODE) NE %str( ) %then %do; 
      %put ERROR: FILEMODE %trim(&FILEMODE) not recognised;
      %return;
    %end;
  %end;

  %* Check INPUT for FILEREF or FILE;
  %if %length(&INPUT) < 9 %then %do;
    %if %sysfunc(fexist(&INPUT)) %then %do;
      %put NOTE: Identified Input "&INPUT" as a FILEFREF;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %put ERROR: Invalid Input FILEREF - "&INPUT";
      %put ERROR: A raw filename must be longer than 8 characters;
      %return;
    %end;
  %end;
  %else %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&INPUT)) %then %do;
    %put NOTE: Identified Input "&INPUT" as a FILE;
    %let INPUT="&INPUT";
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put ERROR: Input file does not exist - "%trim(&INPUT)";
    %return;
  %end;

  %* Check OUTPUT for FILEREF or FILE;
  %if %length(&OUTPUT) < 9 %then %do;
    %if %sysfunc(fexist(&OUTPUT)) %then %do;
      %put NOTE: Identified Output "&OUTPUT" as a FILEFREF;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %put ERROR: Invalid Output FILEREF - "&OUTPUT";
      %put ERROR: A raw filename must be longer than 8 characters;
      %return;
    %end;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put NOTE: Output "&OUTPUT" treated as a FILE;
    %let OUTPUT="&OUTPUT";
  %end;

  %if &OPERATION = ENCODE %then %do;
    %put NOTE: Base64 Encoding Selected.;
    data _null_;
      length b64 $ 76 line $ 57;
      retain line "";

      /* Read one byte at a time from the input file */
      infile &INPUT recfm=F lrecl=1 end=eof;
      input @1 stream $char1.;

      /* Write Base64 with line length of 76 characters */
      file &OUTPUT lrecl=76 &FILEMODE;
      
      /* Place the current byte into the line buffer */
      substr(line,(_N_-(CEIL(_N_/57)-1)*57),1) = byte(rank(stream));

      /* 57 source bytes get base64 encoded to 76 bytes */ 
      if mod(_N_,57)=0 or EOF then do;
        /* Convert the buffer to base64 */
        if eof then b64=put(trim(line),$base64X76.);
        else b64=put(line,$base64X76.); 
        /* Write the base64 string out */
        put b64;
        /* Reset the buffer */
        line="";
      end;

    run;
  %end;
  %else %if &OPERATION = DECODE %then %do;
    %put NOTE: Base64 Decoding Selected;
    data _null_;
      length b64 $ 76 byte $ 1;
      /* We only deal with Base64 files with a max line length of 76 */
      infile &INPUT lrecl=76 truncover length=b64length;
      input @1 b64 $base64X76.;
      if _N_=1 then putlog "NOTE: Detected Base64 Line Length of " b64length;
      file &OUTPUT recfm=F lrecl=1;
      do i=1 to (b64length/4)*3;
        byte=byte(rank(substr(b64,i,1)));
        put byte $char1.;
      end;
    run;
  %end;

%mend;

So, I tried to "translate" the program to only macro language elements:
%let filepath = path to an image;

%macro test;
    %let filrf=myfile;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&filepath.));
    %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&filrf,I,1,F));

    %if &fid > 0 %then
        %do %while(%sysfunc(fread(&fid))=0);
            %let rc=%sysfunc(fget(&fid, c, 76));
            
            %put %sysfunc(putn(%NRQUOTE(&c.),$base64X200.)); /* <-- is not working */
        %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));
%mend test;

%test

So far, as I understand, the var c in %let rc=%sysfunc(fget(&fid, c, 76)); holds the value to be encoded.
I´ve tried to mask the var c with %superq, bquote, nrbquote, but the masking didnt work.
So, what I need is a translation for the original codeblock
    /* Place the current byte into the line buffer */
      substr(line,(_N_-(CEIL(_N_/57)-1)*57),1) = byte(rank(stream));

      /* 57 source bytes get base64 encoded to 76 bytes */ 
      if mod(_N_,57)=0 or EOF then do;
        /* Convert the buffer to base64 */
        if eof then b64=put(trim(line),$base64X76.);
        else b64=put(line,$base64X76.); 
        /* Write the base64 string out */
        put b64;
        /* Reset the buffer */
        line="";
      end;

to macro code
Thanks!!!!

I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Assume you have succeeded in creating the macro.  Can you show how you intend to use it?  Show some example code that would call the macro and explain what you want to happen.

And if the goal is to convert one file into another file why would that need to be done without generating actual SAS code?

Are you asking for something like this macro I wrote 8 years ago?
%macro base64(file);
%local filerc fileref rc fid text len ;

%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Assign fileref and open the file.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%let filerc = 1;
%let fileref = _fread;
%let filerc = %sysfunc(filename(fileref,&file));
%let fid = %sysfunc(fopen(&fileref,s,60,b));

%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Read file and dump as quoted BASE64 text.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%if (&fid > 0) %then %do;
  %do %while(%sysfunc(fread(&fid)) = 0);
    %do %while(not %sysfunc(fget(&fid,text,60)));
      %let len = %eval(4*%sysfunc(ceil(%length(%superq(text))/3)));
      %if (&len) %then "%sysfunc(putc(%superq(text),$base64x&len..))" ;
    %end;
  %end;
  %let rc = %sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
%end;

%*----------------------------------------------------------------------
Clear fileref assigned by macro,
-----------------------------------------------------------------------;
%if ^(&filerc) %then %let rc = %sysfunc(filename(fileref));

%mend base64;

Let's make a file and try it.
filename image temp;
data _null_;
  file image recfm=n;
  put 'this is my image file.';
run;

%put %base64(%sysfunc(pathname(image)));

Result:
"dGhpcyBpcyBteSBpbWFnZSBmaWxlLg=="


Hi Tom, yes, I´m looking for a code like this!
if I use your code 1:1 I get the same result.
But if I use a real image an make a call like:
%put %base64(/sas/Base64/PANDA_small.jpg);
or
filename image "/sas/Base64/PANDA_small.jpg"; /* linux path from the SAS Server*/
%put %base64(%sysfunc(pathname(image)));
I get an error:

NOTE: One or more missing close parentheses have been supplied for the %LENGTH function.
NOTE: One or more missing close parentheses have been supplied for the %CEIL function.
ERROR: Expected close parenthesis after macro function invocation not found.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:
4*
ERROR: The macro BASE64 will stop executing.

I changed the %superq to %bquote--> seems to mask correct, no error. But the result is not as expected, I got repeating blocks of "dGV4dA==" "dGV4dA==" "dGV4dA=="
event the start sequence seems not correct (I have encoded the image via web):
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...

The current macro is designed to emit quoted strings of 80 bytes or less (82 if you count the quotes).  Which should work fine if used to generate a the body of a data step PUT statement.  What is it that you want? You cannot assign the result of a converting a large file into a macro variable as that would be larger than the 64K byte limit of a macro variable.

Why would you change %superq() to %bquote()?? %SUPERQ() takes as input the name of a macro variable.  If you wrap %BQUOTE() around the name of a macro variable then the result is just the name of the macro variable which would explain the constant text being output.

with a real image I get an Error  One or more missing close parentheses have been supplied for the %LENGTH function. NOTE: One or more missing close parentheses have been supplied for the %CEIL function.

The binary bytes are confusing %SYSFUNC().  Better to use actual data step to convert the file.  You will have better luck reading teh converted file, since it will be plain ASCII text.

To do this in pure macro you will need to use external files functions.  I think you should try writing the data steps using ExFF and when you get that working you can convert to pure macro by %SYSFUNCing everything.
External Files Functions
With regards to
%put %sysfunc(putn(%NRQUOTE(&c.),$base64X200.)); /* <-- is not working */

%PUT is NOT the macro equivalent of PUT.

thanks for your comment!
I have tried to sysfunc every thing, but the problem is to mask the c variable
ig: in
%let line = &line.%sysfunc(byte(%sysfunc(rank(&c.))));
it returns an error
ERROR: Der Wert 'JFIF�'n ist kein gültiger SAS-Name.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro JFIF� not resolved.

Did you try Qsysfunc?  and perhaps %SUPERQ for all references to C %qsysfunc(rank(%superq(C))  NOTE that %SUPERQ does not use &
